# sed options N P h d

Tags: shell, sed

i have found this script on the server , would you please support me regarding the aim of the below options , what is the reason behind using N , P , h , d

```
sed '/Text1/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;P;h;
s/.*\(Text2\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text3\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text4\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text5\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text6\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text7\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text8\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text9\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text10\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text11\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text12\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text13\)/\1/;P;g;
s/.*\(Text14\)/\1/;P;d;}'
```

Comment: see manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#advanced-sed ... such questions are not considered fit for this forum... check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking